# How to Edit a todo task on same component in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, ember-data, emberfire

I want to edit a todo task on same list style tag without affecting the other todo present.

Below is the an image of the todo
[image: add todo]

The second image below is when the edit button is clicked.
[image: Delete todo]

What I want to achieve is when the edit button is clicked on a particular todo, I want an input field with the data to appear in the text field and the todo itself to disappear. I want it to happen to one particular todo and not affect all of them.

The code below is what I have tried.

This code tell if it is in edit mode it should display the text input field esle display the todo

todo.hbs

```
<ul class="list-group">
        {{#each model as |todo|}}
          <li class="list-group-item {{if todo.done " isDone"}}">
            {{#if isEdit}}
              <div class="text-input">
                {{input type="text" name="todo" value=todo}}
                <span class="text-info right edit" {{action "cancelEdit" todo}}><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span>
              </div>
            {{else}}
              <span class="round">
                {{input type="checkbox" checked=todo.done click=(action 'toggleTodo' todo)}}
                <label for="checkbox"></label>
              </span>
              <span>
                {{todo.content}} - <span class="date {{if todo.done " isDone"}}">{{todo.createdAt}}</span>
              </span>
              <span class="text-danger right delete" {{action "deleteTodo" todo }}><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
              <span class="text-info right edit" {{action 'editTodo'}}><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span>
            {{/if}}
          </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
```

todo.js

```
export default Controller.extend({
  isEdit: false,
  actions: {
   editTodo: function(todo) {
     this.toggleProperty('isEdit');
   },
   cancelEdit: function () {
     this.toggleProperty('isEdit');
   }
 },
})
```

how can I do what i want to do without affecting other todos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do it is to have a component for each todo, where each component will have an independent internal state (is_editing).

few tips before the real answer :
. give more informations about your versions (ember especially).
. "isDone" className should be 'is-done'.
. do not pass params if you dont use them (editTodo action)

I did not tested this code, but the idea is here:

todo.hbs

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {{#each model as |todo|}}
        {{to-do model=todo}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

templates/components/todo-list-elem.hbs

```
{{#if is_editing}}
  <div class="text-input">
    {{input type="text" name="todo" value=model.content}}
    <span class="text-info right edit" {{action "cancelEdit" todo}}>
      <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
{{else}}
  <span class="round">
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=todo.done click=(action 'toggleTodo')}}
    <label for="checkbox"></label>
  </span>
  <span>
    {{todo.content}} - <span class="date {{if todo.done " isDone"}}">{{todo.createdAt}}</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text-danger right delete" {{action "deleteTodo" todo }}>
    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="text-info right edit" {{action 'editTodo'}}>
    <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
  </span>
{{/if}}
```

components/todo-list-elem.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { computed: { alias } } = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNames:['list-group-item'],
  classNameBindings: ['isDone'], // your class will be is-done id todo.done === true

  isDone: alias('model.done'),

  is_editing: false,

  actions: {

    editTodo() {
      this.set('is_editing', true);
    },

    cancelEdit() {
      this.set('is_editing', false);
    },

    toggleTodo() {
      this.toggleProperty('model.done');
    },

    deleteTodo() {
      this.get('model')
          .destroyRecord()
      ;
    },

  },

});
```

Comment: Thank you. The mistake was not adding the edit property in a child component. this really help.